# Automate Web Browser via Server

Tags: java, web-services, sockets, ubuntu, automation

I need to automate web browsers in the following scenario :

I have a server and many clients. Now whenever server sends command to the clients, the client computer should open web browser, browse a particular site which is provided by the server and after loading of that site, it should send the server exact time it took to load that website.
Any tool or language will be just fine. My client pcs run Ubuntu as the OS.

Also, for the communication between the Server and Clients, I am thinking of employing Java Sockets. Just wanted a comformation regarding it. Am I on the right track?

Basically I need to device an automated testing system in which from the server by just one command, ALL the clients open up their web browsers and browse that particular website that is to be tested.
Security threats are not important (as of now) as I have the administrative access to those testing machines.

Any ideas/suggestions are most welcome.

Comment: It depends upon the target clients. In my case it will be a test center which will record all load times it takes to load that webpage. No security issues as such!

Comment: So you have 'administrator access' to those machines?

Comment: I've deleted some noise.  Please edit the information in the comments, back into the answer so it is more noticeable (hoping you understand now why it is relevant information).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two parts to this program, the first part is having a server hookup with some client side software to start the process, the second is writing a client that will automate a web browser.

Even though you asked the question in regards to java, I'm going to be giving a c++ solution (any solution is better than no answer after more than a month without a solution)

The Client:
Write a Qt Application that uses the [`QWebView`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwebview.html) class to essentially have control of a browser inside a c++ application. This is pretty straightforward and the Qt Documentation helps a lot in this regard.

Have this application connect to a Tcp Server application (can be written in any language from c++, java, even python). This tcp connection between the clients and this server will only be used to 'signal' the clients to start loading a specific page.  This could be monitoring a text configuration file that states which clients are going to load which URL (so on...). This server should also have some way to be 'signaled' to start sending the clients their respective start signals (I'd personally do this through stdin).

The Web Content Server:
Personally I'd use a django server for this part. This would allow you use python to signal the other Tcp Server to start (I'd have a  `view` that when brought up in a browser would send the 'starting signal'). The glory of using this method is that you'd be able to then have another view that accepts POSTs from each of the clients. Each POST could have which client sent it, what url was loaded and how long it took.

Each client would be able to track the time it took for the page to load. This can be done by starting a timer when the [`loadStarted()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwebview.html#loadStarted) signal is emitted after you do the [`load(QUrl)`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwebview.html#load) method and stopping the timer when the [`loadFinished(bool)`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwebview.html#loadFinished) signal that is emitted by the `QWebView`. This information could then be POST'd back to the django server (which with its `model` definitions could be easy to save the information to a database).

Comment: Using this method, you would still be able to test out 'any' website/websever. You don't have to host the original web content at the django server. Realistically, the TCP server could manage everything if you wanted it to, but using the django server allows you to use your already 'automated' web browser to save off, organize, and then very easily analyze and report results off of that data.